# Partial SPA with vuejs in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a laravel application where for admin dashboard I am using vuejs.
I want following urls,

```
example.com/admin/package/index
example.com/admin/package/view/1

example.com/admin/roles/index
example.com/admin/roles/view/1
```

Where,

```
example.com/admin/package/index,
example.com/admin/roles/index
```

should load the page and

```
example.com/admin/package/view/1,
example.com/admin/roles/view/1
```

shouldn't reload the page.
How can I achieve this?

**note I want to use vue-router for,

```
example.com/admin/package/view/1,
example.com/admin/roles/view/1
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is meant by shouldn't reload the page? means you don't want to reload the component or u don't want to navigate from one route to another route?

Comment: That means view pages should be loaded on page. It should show route and load component for view.

Comment: U just don't want to refresh the page. that's it??

Comment: Yes. But for /index pages I want to refresh page.

Comment: I tried whenever I clicked refresh icon in browser it is showing confirmation box whether to leave or stay on page? is that scenario ok?

Comment: I don't think you have understand what this question mean. Sorry.

Comment: As far as I know we can stop page refresh if anyone presses F5 but if anyone clicks browser's refresh we can only show dialog box. We can't bypass the browsers default action.